# Overwrite local changes from remote repository

Tags: git, merge, repository

I have two remote repositories. The first one (Framework) get's pulled into the second one (MySite). I make some changes to MySite, like CSS for example, and push it all to the MySite repo.

Now, if I (or another dev) change a PHP file, User.php for example (which is stored on the Framework repo), on the MySite repo and pull the Framework repo into MySite that User.php file needs to be overwritten using the file on the Framework repo.

Here is my local git config:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
[remote "MySite"]
    url = username@domain.com:mysite
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/MySite/*
    gtPrivateKeyPath = /Users/MY_MAC_USER/.ssh/my_key
    sslVerify = true
[branch "master"]
    remote = MySite
    merge = refs/heads/master
[remote "Framework"]
    url = username@ domain.com:framework
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/Framework/*
    gtPrivateKeyPath = /Users/MY_MAC_USER/.ssh/my_key
    sslVerify = true
```

Folder structure for Framework repo:

```
application/
    modules/
      User/
          User.php
public/
    images/
    themes/
        default/
          css/
settings.php.sample
tmp/
```

Folder structure for MySite repo

```
application/
    modules/
      User/
          User.php
public/
    images/
    themes/
        default/
          css/
        MySite_Theme/
          css/
settings.php
settings.php.sample
tmp/
```

When I pull Framework, it doesn't do anything (unless the files were changed on Framework.

Is it because MySite is the first repo listed?

How can I get Framework to overwrite any files that are in the Framework repo when it get's pulled into MySite?

Answer (score 1):

In the scenario that you have described, the Framework repo is usually referred to as the `upstream` repo.  For you to update your MySite repo getting the changes from the Framework repo and overwriting any changes in the conflicting files, these commands should do that:

```
$ git checkout master  # make sure you're on your master branch in MySite
$ git fetch Framework
$ git merge -s recursive -X theirs Framework/master
```

That will pull in the changes from the Framework repo and any file that is conflicted during the merge will be overwritten with the file from Framework.

Comment: That's what I thought it should be but that is not doing what I thought it would do. I made changes on the MySite repo to files that are in the Framework repo. Then when I pull Framework I want it to overwrite the changes I made to that file. But I can't use reset because there are files on MySite that are not in Framework.

Comment: I've updated my answer to better address your situation.

Comment: That did nothing. There's no conflicts or anything.

Comment: Then I don't think I understand the problem.  Can you show what your folder structure is like and which files you're expecting to be changed?

Comment: Added the folder structure for both repos. When creating a new website, I pull Framework into the new website repo (MySite) then I create some files needed for the site like settings.php, and a theme, then I push it to the remote MySite repo. User.php should only be changed on the Framework repo, then pulled into MySite. But if for some reason another dev does edit User.php on the MySite repo, I want it to be overwritten by the one on Framework when they pull Framework into MySite later on to get updates.

Comment: I very much appreciate you helping me out on this. I am new to Git. I am coming from Subversion. I am starting to think there is a problem with my setup.